# Android Studio - Error while Launch app on 7.0 Version

Tags: android-studio

I don't have any problem when the app is being used on lower versions(lower from 7.0), but when the app is running on device with Android Version of 7.0+ , The app isn't even launching . Here's the error which i keep gets:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1016486028 byte allocation with 22393786 free bytes and 479MB until OOM
                                                                               at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

Comment: You running on emulator or actual device?

Comment: I am running the app on actual device.